# In Excel, how do I count the number of rows in a table that pass a filter with AND and OR logic?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

In Excel, I have data like this:

[image]

I want to put together a formula that counts the rows where Col1 is "a" or "b" and Col2 is "c" or "d".  I highlighted the rows that should be included.  The result should be 4.

I've tried a few options:

(1)  Using COUNTIFS with multiple possible values.  This returns 2 instead of 4.  I don't know why

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,{"a","b"},B2:B7,{"c","d"}))
```

(2)  USING COUNTIFS which each possible combination of filters.  This works, but the formula is long.  And the size of it will explode if I add more filters with more possible values

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"a",B2:B7,"c")+COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"a",B2:B7,"d")+COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"b",B2:B7,"c")+COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"b",B2:B7,"d")
```

(3)  ChatGPT answer.  This returns 0 instead of 4.  I got this from ChatGPT.  It gave me a few different formulas that would return either 0 or 1.

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7, A2:A7, {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"}, B2:B7, {"b","c","d","e","f","g","h"})
```

I'd also like a formula that sums column "N" for rows that pass this filtering.  Can someone give me a hand with this?

Here's the data as text

```
Col1    Col2    N
b   c   1
a   c   2
a   d   3
b   d   4
b   e   5
c   e   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Using arrays in COUNTIFS if the arrays are the same direction (Horizontal vs Vertical) it will do them in pairs.

So:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,{"a","b"},B2:B7,{"c","d"}))
```

Is like doing:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"a",B2:B7,"c")+COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"b",B2:B7,"d")
```

To get all variations, make one vertical and the other horizontal

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A7,{"a","b"},B2:B7,{"c";"d"}))
```

Which will now do all four variations:

[image]

Now the Caveat:  This only works with TWO arrays.  Trying to add a third will put it in sync with one of the other two.  So to do OR with more than two arrays will take a different formula.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your caveat answered my followup question.  I'm going to have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7="a")+($A$2:$A$7="b"),($B$2:$B$7="c")+($B$2:$B$7="d"))
```

This way you can use as many conditions as you need.
But SUMPRODUCT is slower than COUNTIFS.

Answer (score 0):

***I've tested many combinations but these two works without any failure, so I would like to recommend these two:***

```
=SUM(IF((A2:A7={"a","b"})+(B2:B7={"c","d"}),1,0))

=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,"=a")+COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,"=b")+COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,"=c")+COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,"=d")
```

- Adjust cell references & criteria as needed.